# How to refer to transition tables

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have these two tables:

```
create table possiede (
soc1 integer not null,
soc2 integer not null,
primary key (soc1,soc2),
perc double
);

create table contr (
soc1 integer not null,
soc2 integer not null,
primary key(soc1, soc2)
);
```

I have these two triggers in a generic SQL syntax and I need to translate them into MySQL syntax:

```
create trigger contrDir
after insert on possiede
for each row
when percent > 0.5 and (soc1,soc2) not in (select * from contr)
insert into contr values (soc1,soc2);

create trigger contrIndir
after insert on possiede
referencing new table as newTable
for each row
insert into possiede values
(select P.soc1, N.soc2, P.perc+N.perc
from newTable as N join possiede as P on N.soc1 = P.soc2);
```

this was my first try, but it gives me an error on "referencing" keyword ("syntax error, unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting FOR_SYM") and I'm not sure the translation is correct:

```
create trigger controllo
after insert on possiede
REFERENCING new table as newTable
for each row
begin
    insert into possiede (select P.soc1, N.soc2, P.perc+N.perc from
    newTable as N join possiede as P on N.soc1=P.soc2);
    if percent > 0.5 and (soc1,soc2) not in (select * from contr) then
    insert into contr values (soc1,soc2);
    end if;
end;
```

also as you noticed I had to compress two triggers into one because of some MySQL constraints. Could somebody give me the right translation?

Answer (score 0):

Please put the column names inside the braces and use `NEW_TABLE`. In addition, I think the `IN CLAUSE within IF BLOCK` is incorrect as you are checking two columns(soc1 and soc2) against `select * from...`. Please try using the updated query as below:

```
  CREATE TRIGGER controllo
  AFTER INSERT on possiede
  REFERENCING NEW_TABLE AS newTable
  FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO possiede (soc1, soc2, perc) 
      SELECT P.soc1, N.soc2, P.perc+N.perc 
      FROM newTable AS N JOIN possiede AS P ON N.soc1=P.soc2;
      IF percent > 0.5 and soc1 not in (select soc1 from contr)
          and soc2 not in (select soc2 from contr)
        THEN
          INSERT INTO contr VALUES (soc1,soc2);
      END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: I can't understand your answer. I don't neew to put into mi table (soc1, soc2, perc), but what is returned by the select query. I'm pretty sure that that point is correct..

Comment: @user1221297 When you put the braces, its expecting the columns names. Please remove the braces around your select query.

Comment: It's not correct! You eliminated the join in the first insert and I need it to build a kind of recursion!

Comment: also, I still have the same error on keyword "referencing".. it seems that I can't use it in that place..

Comment: @user1221297: I didn't know. Check the answer now and let me know if that helps.

Comment: I think that theoretically your solution is perfect, but I still obtain the same error on REFERENCING keyword: "syntax error, unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting FOR_SYM"

Comment: @user1221297 I think the issue is due to your if condition `in clause` as you are looking for two colums(soc1, soc2) against `select *`. I updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: I tested the double in clause with another table and it works fine. If you have something like "(A,B) in select C,D .." it just compares A with C and B with D. Trust me, the fact is that the "referencing" keyword is not accepted for some reason by my DBMS, but for example this guide says it should:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/Planned-Improvements-in-MySQL-51/1/

Comment: I want to add: if you do some "(A,B) in select *" it compares A with the first column of the select* and B with the second. I don't know what happens if the select* has a different number of columns, but this is not the case..

Comment: @user1221297 Try putting only two columns in the `select`.

Comment: hey man.. I really appreciate your help, but trust me: the problem is not there. I can't even launch the statement because of that error on "referencing" keyword, how could possibly be that select a problem?

Comment: @user1221297: I understand, but I have seen it before that side effect  error is reported but not the original error. If you don't mind, copy the exact query from the answer, remove the `IF` section from it, and let me know, what error you get. This is just to remove one strong doubt I have at moment.

Comment: before launching it I get the usual error on "referencing" keyword and I get an error on "END" final keyword like "syntax error, unexpected END". When I try to launch it I get "Error code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCING NEW_TABLE......'"